How to configure Nginx to serve requests directly to example.com when interceptor server is down
I'm configuring an Nginx server to act as an interceptor for requests to example.com. My goal is to intercept all requests and first direct them to a local server (localhost:9999) which acts as a caching mechanism. This local server checks if the requested file is present locally; if not, it fetches it from example.com and caches it.
However, if the interceptor server is down or returns an error, the requests should still be served directly from example.com. I'm concerned about potential looping issues in my current configuration.
Here's my Nginx configuration:
upstream example_server {
    server example.com;
}

upstream interceptor_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9999;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://interceptor_server;
    
        error_page 502 503 504 = @fallback;
        
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
     location @fallback {
        proxy_pass http://example_server$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host example.com;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}

How can I ensure that there are no potential looping issues with this configuration, and that requests to example.com will still be served correctly even if the interceptor server is down?
